# How to CURL and avoid timeout death (Twitter Down)

Tags: php, twitter, cron, memcached

Twitter is down right now, and one of my site's home pages relies on getting data from Twitter (relies is the problem - it should be more of an accessory feature, as it just shows follow count from its feed).

Here's the code in question:

```
function socials_Twitter_GetFollowerCount($username) {
    $method = function () use ($username) { return file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$username.'&include_entities=true'); };
    $json = cache('bmdtwitter', 3600, $method, false);
    $json = json_decode($json, true);

    return intval($json['followers_count']);
}
```

What is a good way to make it so if Twitter is down (or not responsive for some reasonable amount of time), our site doesn't appear to be down (I think the timeout maybe defaulting to 30-60 seconds or more).

Comment: I think a good start would be to consider offloading the work to a cron task that runs hourly (or similar) to get the latest data and then possibly store it in the database and pull from it. Is this a bad idea - any better solution?

Comment: I think the cron solution makes sense and maybe just a couple of times a day.. unless the number of followers is changing rapidly by an order of magnitude.  Just curious, why the memcached tag and no php tag?

Comment: Very fair question, Spaceghost... I should have posted this on StackOverflow to start (then I would have thought PHP), but I thought for some reason it made sense in the Web Dev section. I'll update the tags... I think I'll go for the cron solution and post our answer as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add context to the `file_get_contents` request and specify a timeout so it will bail out if the request isn't completed in that amount of time.  If you are polling directly on a page load, you may want to consider a very low timeout like 2-3 seconds or so as most requests should be fulfilled within this time limit.

The better option is to do the fetching via cron and have your webpages uses the cached data but here is an example of setting a timeout using `file_get_contents`.

```
function socials_Twitter_GetFollowerCount($username) {
    $method = function () use ($username) {
        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'timeout' => 3
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);

        return file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$username.'&include_entities=true', false, $context);
    };

    $json = cache('bmdtwitter', 3600, $method, false);
    $json = json_decode($json, true);

    return intval($json['followers_count']);
}
```

See [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents), [stream_context_create()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php), and [Context options and parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php).

Comment: Thanks Drew, great idea! I did end up going with the caching option through a background cron task. The timeout option for file_get_contents is another good solution though, especially if I wanted to stick with the straight memcache solution.